# SignalR HttpContext.Current null in IIS 8.0

Tags: c#, signalr, iis-8

I modified the Broadcast Sample from SignalR website documentation, instead of random values, I read random xml files. I'm using the `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` method to access the files and avoid hardcoding the physical path. This runs fine in Windows 7 IIS 7.5 and within Visual Studio 2013, but in Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 I found out that `HttpContext.Current` is `null`. Before asking I searched other questions but didn't found anything like what's happening here.

Here is the whole class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;

using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace SignalRDisplayXML
{
    public struct ReturnDataScheme
    {
        public List<VsDisplaySlotBean> slotsdata;
        public string filename;
    }

    public class XmlTicker
    {
        private readonly static Lazy<XmlTicker> _instance =
            new Lazy<XmlTicker>(() => new XmlTicker(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DisplayXMLHub>().Clients, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data/")));

        private DAO _dao = new DAO();
        private ReturnDataScheme _server_data = new ReturnDataScheme();

        private string _directoryPath = string.Empty;

        private readonly object _processRandomXMLLock = new object();
        private volatile bool _updatingRandomXML = false;
        private readonly Timer _timer;

        private XmlTicker(IHubConnectionContext clients, string path)
        {
            Clients = clients;
            _directoryPath = path;

            _server_data.filename = GetRandomFileName();
            _server_data.slotsdata = _dao.GetVesselAll(_server_data.filename);

            _timer = new Timer(ProcessRandomXML, null, 10000, 10000);
        }

        public static XmlTicker Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance.Value;
            }
        }

        private IHubConnectionContext Clients
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public ReturnDataScheme GetCurrentData()
        {
            return _server_data;
        }

        private void ProcessRandomXML(object state)
        {
            lock (_processRandomXMLLock)
            {
                if (!_updatingRandomXML)
                {
                    _updatingRandomXML = true;

                    _server_data.filename = GetRandomFileName();
                    _server_data.slotsdata = _dao.GetVesselAll(_server_data.filename);

                    Clients.All.DataPush(_server_data);

                    _updatingRandomXML = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private string GetRandomFileName()
        {
            Random randomizer = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            return _directoryPath + "DisplaySlotFDMF00" + randomizer.Next(1, 9).ToString() + ".xml";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, looks like it was changed in SignalR 2.0.

Comment: I'm using version 2.0 actually.

Comment: Yea, don't use HttpContext.Current. If you need to MapPath you can use HostingEnvironment.MapPath (assuming you are in an ASP.NET application)

Comment: HostingEnvironment.MapPath worked fine in all environments. I assume I have an answer here don't know how to proceed.

Comment: DevingNoob - Generally you can ask the person who provided most useful hint to convert comment to answer (like  @dfowler please post as answer), but feel free to post answer yourself. You can also accept your own answer (I'd wait some time to see if one of people who helped decide to post answer).

Comment: `HttpContext` is an ASP thing. SignalR was designed with no ASP dependencies. Thus you should NEVER use `HttpContext` in your SignalR apps.

Comment: @Aron: If you should not be using HttpContext, What do you suggest would be a better context to use? I am using a repository pattern, and I use httpcontext.current to set my context to the current context if it exists, which apparently in 8.1 and 2012 it is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HostingEnvironment.MapPath instead of HttpContext.MapPath.

Comment: Worked fine in all environments. Thank you.